# How to get all predefined constant in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to see all predefined constant in library.

A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script (except for magic constants, which aren't actually constants).

A constant is case-sensitive by default. By convention, constant identifiers are always uppercase.

Comment: don't people ever read **[the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)**?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann no, actually many many people who start to learn programming are not aware that reading the documentation is an option. I guess that is because most documentations of every day utilities are so ridiculous and needless that we learn to ignore them. It is an important lesson to learn to _read_ and _understand_ what is said in a documentation.

Comment: @arkascha good point, but my question is still valid with "read tutorials" or "use search engines". i see many questions where simply *typing the title word for word* into google leads to the desired result. (like this one). also: the documentations for the two languages i use most, php and c#, actually are quite good.

Comment: @arkascha Also its quite funny that he asks a simple question, whichs answer can be googeld in 2 seconds, but explain us what constants are.

Comment: @Twinfriends no - the **really** funny thing is that his explanation is copypasted **from** (a different page of) the PHP-manual.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann omg just entered his text in google... made my day. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all php constant

```
$cons = get_defined_constants(true);
var_dump($cons);
```

here the manual from [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php).